# Is it valid to compare a double with an int in java?

Tags: java, comparison, int, double, primitive-types

```
Utilities.getDistance(uni, enemyuni) <= uni.getAttackRange()
```

Utilities.getDistance returns double and getAttackRange returns int. The above code is part of an if statement and it needs to be true. So is the comparison valid?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: How can I test if it's valid. Compiler accepts it but I can't know if the actual numeric values are indeed compared.

Comment: Have you tried it your self?? A simple test in java code could have sufficed. check my answer for the same

Comment: It is valid, but you may get interesting results in edge cases if you don't specify a precision on the double...

Comment: @Vineet Verma yea I didn't know I could actually print the result of a logical statement, I'm kinda 2 days old in Java. Thanks a lot though

Comment: With the caveat from @PinnyM, I should point out that converting `int` to `double` is lossless, but promoting `long` to `double` is lossy. That is, there are some values of type `long` for which no exact value of type `double` exists, so the conversion will lose information. Not so with `int` to `double`, but also true with `int` to `float`.

Comment: @Crone: This is generally true, regardless of language, when converting a value of an integer type to a value of a floating-point type, when the number of bits required by the integer type is greater than the number of bits required by the mantissa of the floating-point type.

Comment: @NathanD.Ryan Could you please point out one specific `long` literal for which `System.out.println(l == (double)l)` prints `false`? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Your statement will always print true, because `l` is being promoted to a value of type `long` on both sides of the equality. However, `System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE)` will print something different than `System.out.println((double)Long.MAX_VALUE)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Sorry, I meant to say that `l` is being promoted to a value of type *`double`* on both sides of the equality (in accordance with the rules of binary numeric promotion).

Comment: @NathanD.Ryan Yes, I was actually testing with the correct stuff, but simplified it the wrong way for the comment. In the meantime I fixed another minor issue with my code, so here is the smallest long that fails: `long l = (1L << 53) + 1;
    double d = l;
    System.out.println((long)d == l);`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, it's valid - it will promote the `int` to a `double` before performing the comparison.

See [JLS section 15.20.1 (Numerical Comparison Operators)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) which links to [JLS section 5.6.2 (Binary Numeric Promotion)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

From the latter:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - ...

Answer (score 8):

When performing operations (including comparisons) with two different numerical types, Java will perform an implicit widening conversion. This means that when you compare a `double` with an `int`, the `int` is converted to a `double` so that Java can then compare the values as two `double`s. So the short answer is yes, comparing an int and a double is valid, with a caveat.

The problem is that that you should not compare two floating-piont values for equality using `==`, `<=`, or `>=` operators because of possible errors in precision. Also, you need to be careful about the special values which a double can take: `NaN`, `POSITIVE_INFINITY`, and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. I strongly suggest you do some research and learn about these problems when comparing `double`s.

Comment: Funny thing is this is my professors code. But yea I will investigate the subject now

Comment: @Crone For a school assignment, you probably can ignore these edge cases, but you should still know about them. Choosing to ignore them is preferrably than complete ignorance.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with comparing a `double` with `<=` or `>=` against an `int`. Only exact equality might be questionable.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik <= or >= may give undesirable results in some cases, just like == does.

Comment: "Some cases" is not as unpredictable as you picture it and when calculating Euclidian distance, it would be perfectly alright.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Granted, it is not entirely unpredictable, just as it is not with `==`. There is plenty of information available about comparing floating point values for equality, so if the OP needs/wants more detail, they can research it further.

Comment: Yea I can understand this is a case of way too much detail for a university code. I also completely agree with the fact that tmi can be really harmful when you start to learn a language. Thanks a lot for the input guys

Comment: All Integers up to 2^52 are exactly represented as double. So there is no problem to compare int with double, even for equality, if you know it stores an integer, which could be not true if you operate over that variable.

Answer (score 3):

yes it is absolutely valid compare int datatype and double datatype..

```
int i =10;
double j= 10.0;
 if (i==j)
{
System.out.println("IT IS TRUE");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be fine. **In floating point operation/comparisons, if one argument is floating/double** then **other one being int is also promoted to the same.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes it valid, and your code should work as expected without any glitch, but this is not the best practice, 
static code analyzers like SonarQube shows this as a "Major" "Bug",

[Major Bug img from sonarQube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aad4y.png)

[Major Bug description from sonarQube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnYUC.png)

so, the right way to do this can be,

```
Double.compare(val1,val2)==0
```

if any parameter are not floating point variable, they will be promoted to floating point.

Answer (score 0):

It will be ok.

Java will simply return true of the numerical value is equal:

```
    int n = 10;
    double f = 10.0;
    System.out.println(f==n);
```

The code above prints true.

Comment: You must be careful (and usually even avoid) comparing floating-point values with the `==` operator.

Comment: And what do you want to compare these 2 values with ?

Comment: All `int`s are exactly representable as `double`.