# Java cast confusing

Tags: java, casting

everyone! this problem is about Java cast behavior.
Here is the code:

```
public static int dotProduct(double[] v1, double[] v2){
    //here the type of res is int
    int res = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.dimension; i++){
        res += v1[i] * v2[i];   // no errors
        res = res + v1[i] * v2[i];  // show cast errors
    }
    return res;
}
```

can someone explains why this code does not throw cast error when use "+=" in eclipse. thanks.

Comment: There **must** be a duplicate to this question already on this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297207/is-it-valid-to-compare-a-double-with-an-int-in-java

Asks essentially the same question. The accepted answer has the correct information.