# Why java Integer wrapper == primitive double compiles while assigning a primitive int to a Double wrapper is not allowed

Tags: java

The following code compiles fine and yields true in java.
I have read that java won't do two conversions at once, like when assigning an **int** literal value(or variable) to a **Double** wrapper reference. 
So why is it that this compiles fine in comparison with using = operator?

```
double double1 = 3.00;
Integer wInt = new Integer("3");
if(wInt == double1);
```

Comment: It's just an optimization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it valid to compare a double with an int in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297207/is-it-valid-to-compare-a-double-with-an-int-in-java)

Comment: @ModusTollens That question doesn't cover unboxing combined with widening.

Comment: @user1133275 optimization of *what*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like other mathematical operators such as `+`, the `==` operator performs [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) on its operands.

> When an operator applies *binary numeric promotion* to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands...

The compiler first unboxes the `Integer` to an `int`, then widens the `int` to a `double`.  It will perform both if the unboxing occurs first.

Java will perform both conversions implicitly for many operators:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators `*`, `/`, and `%` (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types `+` and `-` (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators `==` and `!=` (§15.21.1)
> - The integer bitwise operators `&`, `^`, and `|` (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator `? :` (§15.25)

Comment: so your explanation is that "two conversions" are allowed only when Unboxing happens first, but not the other way around? (Boxing and then converting)

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought including `?:` in the quote at the bottom was sufficient.

Comment: @aligh Yes, that's what the quote from the JLS explicitly states.  The conversions happen "in order".

Comment: It may actually do a total of **four** conversions. Example: If expression is `Byte + Short`, then it will do `Byte → byte` *(unbox)*, `byte → int` *(widen)*, `Short → short` *(unbox)*, and `short → int` *(widen)*.