# does anyone have an explanation about the difference in '==' and '.equals().' in the below code?

Tags: java

does anyone have an explanation for the a.equals(b) and a==b in the above code..?
you can refer the image also, which shows the output for the following code.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer  a=new Integer(10);
            double  b=10;
            System.out.println(a==b);
            System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would you use String.Equals over ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/why-would-you-use-string-equals-over)

Comment: Also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297207/is-it-valid-to-compare-a-double-with-an-int-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you see the `equals` method in `Integer` class. Since the `b` is not the `instance` of `Integer` it returns `false`.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) `.equals() Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is an Integer object that contains the same int value as this object.`

Since `b` is NOT an Integer object, it returns false.